# Sails.JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

When trying to run my simple Sails.JS app (with swaggerui included), I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

debug: hookPath: DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails-swagger\dist\api\hooks\swagger
debug: marlinspike (swagger): loading config from DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails-swagger\dist\config
debug: marlinspike (swagger): loading Services from DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails-swagger\dist\api\services...
warn: marlinspike (swagger): no Services found. skipping
debug: marlinspike (swagger): loading Models...
debug: marlinspike (swagger): loading Controllers...
debug: marlinspike (swagger): loading Policies...
warn: marlinspike (swagger): no Policies found. skipping
DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails-swagger\dist\api\hooks\swagger\index.js:49
        hook.doc = _libXfmr2['default'].getSwagger(_this.sails, _this.sails.config.swagger.pkg);
                                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pkg' of undefined
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails-swagger\dist\api\hooks\swagger\index.js:49:91
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\after.js:91:14
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:721:13
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17)
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at Sails.<anonymous> (DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:718:17)
    at Sails.<anonymous> (DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:37)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Sails.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Sails.emitter.emit (DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\after.js:50:11)
    at sailsReady (DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\lib\app\lift.js:53:11)
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:721:13
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at DummyPath\Software\MyService\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:269:32
```

npm install, npm uninstall sails or npm cache clear doesn't work.
I've already tried to reinstall grunt-cli as well and sails-swagger again...
Does anyone have a solution here?

Issue on [github.com](https://github.com/trailsjs/sails-swagger/issues/45) is opened, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using sails-swagger you also have to create a config file for swagger in the config directory of your sails application. This config file sets a pkg variable that points to the package.json file of your sails application.

The error above is basically saying that property pkg cannot be found and hence swagger will not work.

To solve this issue, first create a file called swagger.js in the config directory.

Then add the following to the swagger.js file

```
module.exports.swagger = {
  /**
   * require() the package.json file for your Sails app.
   */
  pkg: require('../package'),
  ui: {
    url: 'http://swaggerui.balderdash.io'
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Glen, I've missed to mark this as resolved. The developer has already shown me the solution on github: https://github.com/trailsjs/sails-swagger/issues/45 Nevertheless, your solution is correct ;)